# systemd run script before network up

Tags: linux, wireless-networking, systemd, hostapd

I am setting up an old laptop as a wireless router/extender and I need to split the network interface before hostapd starts and before netctl runs

`# iw dev wlan0 interface add wlan0_sta type managed addr 12:34:56:78:ab:cd`
   `# iw dev wlan0 interface add wlan0_ap  type managed addr 12:34:56:78:ab:ce`

I know I could write a systemd file to run before the network is up, https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/229048/how-to-start-a-systemd-service-before-networking-starts, But I would like to just create a script to do it. It this possible?

I am running Arch Linux on a dell Inspiron 1720.

Answer (score 0):

The [ExecStartPre](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.service.html#ExecStartPre=) directive might help you.

First create a directory named after the systemd serve you want to run something before, like:

```
 mkdir /etc/systemd/system/myservice.d
```

Then add create a new file in that directory. The file name doesn't matter.

```
# In /etc/systemd/system/myservice.d/run-before.conf
[Service]
ExecStartPre=/path/to/my/command
```

I believe you can have multiple `ExecStartPre` lines which will be run in order.